# Personalizar tabla generada con sjPlot en Rmarkdown

Tags: r, tablas, model, r-markdown

Estoy estimando **dos modelos logit binomial** y quiero presentar los resultados en una **tabla estilizada**. El código de los modelos son los siguientes:

```
library(readxl)
datos_modelo <- read_excel("datos_def_excel")

library(glm2)
modelo_logit_viv <- glm2( SAP ~sexo + edad + IMC + niv_est, 
                         data = datos_modelo, family = binomial(link = "logit"),na.action = "na.omit")

modelo_logit <- glm2(SAP ~ sexo + edad + IMC + niv_est,
                    data = modelo_logit_viv$model, family = binomial(link = "logit"),na.action = "na.omit")
```

( Transformo las variables que me interesan a tipo factor y creo la lista `etiqs_model` para cambiar el nombre de las etiquetas que aparecen en la tabla que genero a continuación)

```
library(sjPlot)
tab_model(modelo_logit,modelo_logit_viv,transform = "exp", title = "Salud autopercibida",pred.labels = etiqs_model, wrap.labels = 10,
           string.pred = "Variables",dv.labels = c("Modelo I","Modelo II"),show.se = TRUE,show.r2 = TRUE,
           string.est = "ODD-R", p.style = "numeric", string.se = "Er. estánd.",show.ci = FALSE)
```

En este ejemplo ambos modelos tienen las mismas variables, pero en mi trabajo las variables difieren y por eso genero **una tabla con dos modelos**.
Esto me genera la siguiente tabla:
[image: Tabla generada]

Mis preguntas son:

- ¿Cómo puedo **aumentar el espacio entre columnas** para que el texto de la primera columna no aparezca tan junto? Si os fijáis aparece el texto "ODD-R" demasiado pegado a "Er. estánd"
- ¿Cómo puedo **añadir una línea vertical o una separación mayor** entre los resultados del Modelo I y Modelo II?

Por lo que he buscado,creo que tengo que añadir el argumento `list=CSS(...)` en `tab_model` pero no sé los parámetros que debo incluir en `list=CSS(...)`. La mayor ayuda que he encontrado al respecto es [esta](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/articles/table_css.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente, la forma de ajustar la apariencia de las tablas, es usando `css`. Un ejemplo básico:

```
library(sjPlot)
data(efc)
m1 <- lm(barthtot ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + c172code, data = efc)
m2 <- lm(barthtot ~ nur_pst + c172code + e42dep, data = efc)
tab <- tab_model(m1, m2)
tab
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que buscas:

- Agregar algo de `padding` a una columna en particular. En este ejemplo lo haremos sobre la primer `Estimates` del primer modelo, es la segunda columna
- Agregar un borde vertical entre los dos modelos, agregando `border` a la cuarta columna.

Lo primero, es usar `cat(tab$page.style)` para entender que estilos podemos configurar de nuestra tabla, en este ejemplo, usaremos: `.col2` y `.col4`, y la idea es hacer algo así:

```
CSS <- list(
  css.col2 = 'padding-right: 50px;',
  css.col4 = 'border-right: 1px solid black'
)

tab <- tab_model(m1, m2, CSS = CSS) 
tab
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Documentación adicional que te puede ser útil:

- [Customizing HTML tables](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/articles/table_css.html)
- [CSS](https://devdocs.io/css/)